# Oracle SQL - Find original ID in a chain

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data that looks like this:

```
ACT_ID  ACT_ID_FROM
1A  
1B       1A
1C       1B
2A  
2B       2A
2C       2B
```

However, I'd like to be able to create a third column for the data so it looks like this:

```
     ACT_ID ACT_ID_FROM ORIG_ID
1A                   1A
1B      1A           1A
1C      1B           1A
2A                   2A
2B      2A           2A
2C      2B           2A
```

Basically, I'm interested in the originating ID of each line, so 1C and 1B both originally came from ACT_ID 1A (which can be determined from the ACT_ID_FROM column), but I'm not sure how to get the 1A out, particularly when there have been a number of IDs in a chain.  I'm using oracle 10g.

A similar question has already been asked here: [Find last record in a single-table chain (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709615/find-last-record-in-a-single-table-chain-sql-server) but I'm not sure how to apply this to my own problem.

Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance.

Comment: the third line of the first table should be `1C 1B`, right?

Comment: Yes, it goes 1A -> 1B -> 1C, so 1C came from 1B, and 1B came from 1A, 1A was the originating instance so it came from nowhere.  I've fixed it now, thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by selecting rows in [hierarchical](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) order using `start with` and `connect by` clauses, and `connect_by_root()` operator:

```
SQL> with t1(act_id, act_id_from) as(
  2    select '1A', null from dual union all
  3    select '1B', '1A' from dual union all
  4    select '1C', '1B' from dual union all
  5    select '2A', null from dual union all
  6    select '2B', '2A' from dual union all
  7    select '2C', '2B' from dual
  8  )
  9  select act_id
 10       , act_id_from
 11       , connect_by_root(act_id) as orig_id
 12    from t1
 13   start with act_id_from is null
 14  connect by prior act_id = act_id_from
 15  /
```

Result:

```
ACT_ID ACT_ID_FROM ORIG_ID
------ ----------- ---------
1A                 1A
1B     1A          1A
1C     1B          1A
2A                 2A
2B     2A          2A
2C     2B          2A

6 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and clear response.  I've used connect_by_root previously, but it didn't even cross my mind to use it.  Thanks, you've just made an extremely frustrating process a lot more bearable!